# Okta Authentication To Know User Logged In The Website First Time

Tags: angular, okta, okta-api

I'm using Okta Authentication in our angular 14 application, This is a SPA.
How can I know that The currently authenticated user logged in to the application the first time so that we can fetch the details of that user's last login date & time etc.?

```
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
constructor(public oktaAuth: OktaAuthService....

function login(){
this.oktaAuth.getUser()  //** using this not able to get isNewuser or Not

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider calling the [User API](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#get-current-user) by API token from a backend service and then retrieve all info about the user before the login.
This could be achieved by calling above API before sending user/pwd to Okta and then check if "lastLogin" field is valued or not.